# Mail app: How to check which account is an email being sent to?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I receive a number of emails to mailing lists on my Mac, using Mail app. The recipient of these emails is not my email but the mailing list.

This is important information to unsubscribe, for instance.

How do I know which account is this email being sent to?

Comment: The "To" line will show which account it was sent to.

Comment: @SolarMike Not necessarily if the mail goes to a mailing list.

Comment: If you hover your pointer over the to field in the normal message view, is there a down caret you can select to see which mail it was addressed to? Or are you thinking that field is untrusted and you need a deeper header / actually delivered to address? Some mail headers can be forged or not correct in practice.

Comment: @bmike I only see the mailing list address.

Comment: If you have Column Layout and you are in All Inbox hover over column header(s) and right click. On pop-up window select Mailbox. There will column with Inbox - <account name> displayed.

Comment: But, if it is to unsubscribe, then you should be looking for who it was sent FROM...

Answer (score 1):

With the mail selected in Mail, go to **View** -> **Message** and select **All Headers** (you can also just press <kbd>Shift-Cmd-H</kbd>). This will show you all the header fields, look for one which is called `Delivered-To:`.

PS:

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, the header is hundreds of lines long. I couldn't find "delivered-to" once I pasted it onto text file and did search there.

Comment: @Adelita Case may matter here. If you already have the mail in a text file, you probably can also just search for each of your mail addresses until you find a match. It must be in there somewhere, otherwise it wouldn't get delivered.

Comment: Whilst this answer and your comment are correct, I prefer to use View > Message > Raw Source. With that the `Delivered-To:` is at the top!